# Jquery scrollbar plugin and text input filter

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins

I am using the [tiny scrollbar plugin](http://baijs.nl/tinyscrollbar/) and implementation of [this example](http://www.designchemical.com/blog/index.php/jquery/live-text-search-function-using-jquery/).
All is working great but I have now come across a problem.

the #filteredlist ul is a fixed height. When you scroll without the filter its fine, but once you use the filter the scrollbar stays the same size and you can scroll blank space.

- I want to resize the scrollbar once I have filtered the list.
- Also I want to be able to hide the text input #filter if the origional count is < 4 not the filtered count

  ```
  $(document).ready(function() { 
     $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar({size: 'auto', sizethumb: 'auto' });

          $("#filter").keyup(function(){

              // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
              var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
              // Loop through the comment list
              $(".filteredlist li").each(function(){
                  // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
                  if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                      $(this).fadeOut();
                  // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
                  } else {
                      $(this).show();
                      count++;
                  }
              });
           });        
          });


      <form id="live-search" action="" class="styledsearch" method="post">
      <input type="text" class="text-input" id="filter" value="" />
      </form>

            <ul class="filteredlist">
            <li>Dynamic list 1</li>
            <li>Dynamic list 2</li>
            <li>Dynamic list 3</li>
            <li>Dynamic list 4</li>
            <li>Dynamic list 5</li>
            </ul>
  ```

Any help guidance would be fantastic.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to call

```
  $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar({size: 'auto', sizethumb: 'auto' });
```

again when you updated the list.

Something like:

```
    $("#filter").keyup(function(){

        // Retrieve the input field text and reset the count to zero
        var filter = $(this).val(), count = 0;
        // Loop through the comment list
        $(".filteredlist li").each(function(){
            // If the list item does not contain the text phrase fade it out
            if ($(this).text().search(new RegExp(filter, "i")) < 0) {
                $(this).fadeOut();
            // Show the list item if the phrase matches and increase the count by 1
            } else {
                $(this).show();
                count++;
            }
        });
        $('#scrollbar').tinyscrollbar({size: 'auto', sizethumb: 'auto' });
     });
```

EDIT:

Not sure if I understood your additional question, but is this what you meant?

```
if ($("ul.filteredlist li").size() < 4 ){ 
  $("#filter").hide();
} else {
  $("#filter").show();
}
```

You can run it onReady. http://jsfiddle.net/LSSTB/1/

Comment: thnks for the reply, I have implemented this but although it works well it does not always work. Its strange, sometimes the scroll bar resizes sometimes no change.

Comment: I believe those are timing issues. It may execute before all the list is updated. I would suggest to try and replace fadeOut with hide. Just to see if now it resizes more often.

Comment: Or... Not the best choice, but you can try to update the list on each iteration.

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks for the help, works perfectly now. Do you have any suggestions about the hiding of the text input if the original count is < 4 not the filtered count

Comment: I meant that if the original <li> count is < 4 hide #filter, if > 4 show filter. (Filter is determined on page load) Once filter is show i dont want it to be hidden if the filter returns < 4 values.

Comment: Sorry. Not sure why I thought you have a selector list. Will update my code in a sec. Now the code should work as you want, just put it in $(document).ready